# shared hosted web server used as forward proxy

Tags: webserver, proxy, shared-hosting

When setting up personal anonymous forward proxy server, different hosting can be chosen. In the case of shared hosting, web server, transformed into proxy server, shares it's IP with hundreds of other websites and differs only in PORT. Wouldn't having the same IP as other websites (but different PORT) expose the fact that the client must indeed be using a proxy server?

Comment: How would anyone determine this, by pulling down all records from root nameservers and checking those tables for occurrences of the same IP? Plus how do they differentiate between someone proxying through the machine and the machine simply pulling down resources, acting like a CDN node? What precisely are you trying to accomplish and what precisely are you concerned about?

Comment: This is more of an idea I came up with. I am trying to evaluate how easy is to identify if someone is using proxy. To the best of my humble understanding, using shared hosting exposes the fact that someone is behind a proxy. I noticed that some websites serve different content, depending on the usage of proxy(geographic factor wasn't the problem), although the proxy doesn't state that it is, in fact a proxy. My guess is that this proxy was used before (not sure if this is true) and it was marked as "stale". So the goal is to represent yourself as a client and not a proxy using my own proxy.

Comment: Possibly by using shared hosting, since well, this is the cheapest way to go.

Comment: If your goal is to truly hide your origin, I think you can find out how difficult and complex such a goal is by looking at projects like Tor. If you're wondering if a standard web server can figure out that you're behind a proxy, probably not at all, so long as your proxy isn't adding any special headers that indicates that it is a proxy, or modifying the headers in a tell-tale way to identify itself as a proxy.

Comment: The proxy also has to function in a standard compliant way. When I've developed proxies in the past, and screwed up aspects, some web services caught on to how "odd" my traffic/requests/responses appeared and flagged me as things like a web scraper, and temporarily banned my IP.

Comment: nah, I no one will read proxy logs to find out where the next node is. My guess was that there are companies that store proxies and sell that data to other companies. Regarding odd traffic, is there a way to check what the proxy is doing from client side? I bought a proxy, so I have no access to the code on the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40447/discussion-between-technik-empire-and-sanjihan).